# Converting from cylindrical to spherical coordinates for a field

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-fields, spherical-coordinates, cylindrical-coordinates

Say I have the field

$$F(r,\theta,z) = 5r\hat{r}+z\hat{\theta}+\theta\hat{z}.$$

Using the conversions found in the source transformations table in the 3rd row, 2nd column of [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates#Non-trivial_calculation_rules), [image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHF8t.png) I came up with the following transformation matrix:
\begin{Bmatrix} 
   F_{\rho}  \\
   F_{\theta}  \\
   F_{\psi}  \\
   \end{Bmatrix} =
\begin{Bmatrix} 
   \sin{\theta} & 0 & \cos{\theta}  \\
   0 & 1 & 0  \\
   \cos{\theta} & 0 & -\sin{\theta}  \\
   \end{Bmatrix} *

\begin{Bmatrix} 
   F_{r}  \\
   F_{\theta}  \\
   F_{z}  \\
   \end{Bmatrix}

Sorry for the weird formatting, but it should be vect1 = matrix*vect2. Upon performing this on the specified vector field in cylindrical coordinates, I get something in terms of $r$, $z$, and $\theta$, instead of the same variables in spherical coordinates. How do I fix this, because the outputted vector is definitely not in spherical coordinates?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: You don't have to remember the conversion tables... open up the book named "Tensor calculus and anlysis of moving surfaces" by Pavel Grinfeld.. all of this is covered in first section

Comment: I am not a very good explainer but I tried to make a video based on this topic / "how to achieve invariance" [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=25SoOdhFEH0)

Comment: In the wiki page, see second table under Unit Vector conversion. See row $2$ column $3$.  Also note what you write as $\theta$ here is written as $\varphi$ on that page.